# IE6 crash when using HttpWebRequest and Css

Tags: html, css, ajax, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6

My web application is Asp.NET 2.0 and in one page, i'm using HttpWebRequest to load some content into a container page. This works well within Firefox, IE7/8, Safari but it crashes IE6. It hangs or shuts down.

The content page i'm trying to read is called tmp.html and if i call it directly (using IE6) then it seems ok. The html code inside tmp.html is :

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="background-image: url(images/jpg/alt_right_top.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;">
        <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="bottom">
                <img src="images/jpg/baslik_icindekiler.jpg" style="margin-top: 20px;"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

this crashes the browser but if i remove the line : `"background-image: url(images/jpg/alt_right_top.png);"` then it shows up correctly even if i call it through HttpWebRequest.

example link : http://www.smilevitamin.com/smilevitamin/vitamin.aspx

Any ideas? Is this an Internet Explorer 6 bug?

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use any JavaScript framework that is tested for these kind of things?
[Jquery](http://jquery.com/) is a good example.

Comment: what do you mean ? you mean to set the background image using javascript ?